# Is it possible to know if the user made the call after clicking tel link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make something like. When a user clicks on a tel link it will open the call screen. And after the user make the call it will redirect the user to a thank you page. By far I've done this.

```
$(".call").click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    window.open("tel:phone_number");
    window.location.href = "thank_you_page.php";
});
```

By using the above codes, I almost achieved what I wanted. When the user click on the tel link it opens the call screen and also redirect them to the thank you page. But I want the user to be redirected only if the user make the call. If the user cancel the call screen or doesn't make the call, then it is not appropriate to redirect him/her to a thank you page.

1. Is it possible to know the user action and achieve what I described above?

And one more thing, on Desktop it opens the call alert box to a new tab with blank page.
And the blank page stays even after closing the alert box. I have to close the tab manually.

I tried `window.open("tel:phone_number","_self");` but it doesn't open the Call Alert Box at all, but redirects to the thank you page.

2. How to make the Call Alert Box open in the same page, like it does when the tel link is used in html anchor tag `<a href="tel:number">` like this?

Comment: It shouldn't be possible to confirm, because for a call to take place the user's action is outside of the browser.

Comment: No I don't think so. The reason I say this is because I have experience working with the "Google My Business" API, which tracks phone icon clicks for a business - see https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/Metric (ACTIONS_PHONE). The GMB API only tracks the clicks